# DFPlayer Mini does not boot reliably after being powered down

Tags: arduino-nano, mosfet

For a low power project, I need to power up the DFPlayer Mini module, let it say something, and power it down again using an Arduino Nano (w/o power regulator and LEDs). In the idle time, the Arduino will go to deep sleep. This is to be repeated regularly, e.g. on a daily basis. However, it seems I'm not able to power the module down in the right fashion. The module is connected to the Arduino via an n-channel logic-level MOSFET (IRLZ44N), such that the Player's VCC is permanently at ~5.3 V (4x1.3 V batteries), but no current can flow through the FET's drain to ground (source) if the MOSFET is not switched on via one of the Arduinos pins on its gate. I have a pull-down resistor on the gate to prevent a floating state and a 100uF capacitor from 5V to GND, otherwise turning on the MOSFET apparently causes a current spike which can reset the Arduino. The player's RX is protected by a 1k resistor as described in several tutorials. 5.3 V is not exactly within the specs of the player, but it doesn't seem to be the issue, as the following code works in the sense that the player does its job consistently fine in the first iteration of the loop but then fails every time afterwards.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <LowPower.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h>

// MP3 module is powered through logic-level MOSFET
// 100uF capacitor is connected across 5V - GND to smoothen current spikes
static const int MP3Power = 2;
static const int MP3Tx    = 3;
static const int MP3Rx    = 4;
static const int MP3Baud  = 9600; // Default hardware baud rate

uint32_t loop_count = 50000; // large loop_count: start into working loop after reset
//unsigned long loop_max;

uint32_t loop_max   = 1;     // 8 sec * 1 ~ 8 sec

DFRobotDFPlayerMini player;
SoftwareSerial MP3serial(MP3Rx, MP3Tx); // RX, TX

void speak(int filenumber, int volume=20);

void setup() {
  // Set all pins connected to MOSFET gates as low outputs.
  pinMode(MP3Power, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(MP3Power, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (loop_count < loop_max) {
    // increase loop counter, then go to deep sleep for 8 sec.
    loop_count++;
    LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
  } else {
    // reset loop count, speak
    loop_count = 0;
    speak(1);
  }
}

void speak(int filenumber, int volume) {
  // turn on power for mp3 module
  digitalWrite(MP3Power, HIGH);
  // wait for the module to cope with being powered up
  // it does light up its LED when powered up and doesn't seem to like
  // to be talked to right away.
  delay(1500);

  // initialise mp3 serial communication
  MP3serial.begin(MP3Baud);
  // sometimes I added another delay here, but it didn't really change to much.

  if (!player.begin(MP3serial)) {
    // MP3 Player can't start -- shut down everything and return early (but gracefully?)
    /*
     * This is where I end up after the first time worked. I can confirm this e.g. by blinking an
     * LED in here or reading the player's state, which returns a timeout error, whatever this means.
     */
    MP3serial.flush();
    MP3serial.end();
    digitalWrite(MP3Power, LOW);
    delay(100);
    return ;
  }

  player.setTimeOut(1000);
  player.EQ(DFPLAYER_EQ_POP);
  player.outputDevice(DFPLAYER_DEVICE_SD);

  player.volume(volume);
  player.playMp3Folder(filenumber);

  // enter this loop until playing is finished
  while (true) {
    delay(250); // give the player a little time before querying
    int i = player.readState();
    delay(250); // give the player a little more time, just in case
    if (i != 1) {
      // 1 means playing, break out when finished
      break;
    }
  }

  // close mp3 module
  MP3serial.flush();
  MP3serial.end();
  // wait a bit?
  delay(100);
  // turn off power
  digitalWrite(MP3Power, LOW);
  // wait until everything is turned off for good
  delay(100);

  // I also tried this, but it didn't really change anything
  //pinMode(MP3Tx,OUTPUT); digitalWrite(MP3Tx, HIGH); 
  //pinMode(MP3Rx,OUTPUT); digitalWrite(MP3Rx, HIGH);
}
```

I also managed to obtain some delay settings via trial and error such that **sometimes** it would play another track, but this was very unstable. As you can see, I have a lot of delays, which makes me unhappy. I suspect that the error lies somewhere within the part which powers down the DFPlayer mini module. Can someone give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

[image: wiring]
[image: schematic]

Comment: please add a schematic diagram of the circuit

Comment: I added two diagrams, are these ok?

Comment: On the breadboard, the top blue rail doesn't have a connection to the bottom blue rail. In the schematic, the GND pin on the DFPLAYER MINI is not connected to anything.

Comment: Well, there's no direct connection between the top and bottom blue rails as the point of the MOSFET is to disconnect them if it is switched off. They are connected to the MOSFET on its drain and source terminals, respectively. So this is intended. The DFPlayer Mini's pin 10 (GND) isn't connected to anything, but the same GND (pin 7) is actually connected to the top blue rail. I could connect pin 7 and 10, but it doesn't make any difference, since they are already connected internally.

Comment: It would be better to have a high-side MOSFET switch to control the power to the DFPLAYER and connect both GNDs to ground.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have two logic-level MOSFET types available: IRLZ44N (the one I used so far) and IRL540N, both are N-channel enhancement mode MOSFETs. As written in the question, the first run does work completely fine, so the power setup seems to work (power is off initially!). The problem arises only after I power down the DFPlayer and power it up again. It actually does power up again, but communication doesn't seem to work properly, as I get these timeout errors. Hence, I actually assume this is rather a software issue due to turning the serial communication off and on again.

Comment: Try using a mechanical switch or wire link in place of a high-side MOSFET switch to see if you can depower and repower the DFPLAYER and continue successfully with the programme.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I removed the MOSFET completely from the breadboard and instead bridged the top blue rail with the bottom one (so actually there's no switch involved anymore). I left the sketch as above. The same thing happens: The player works the first time after powering up / resetting the Arduino, then starting with the second iteration, the player fails to play the file each time.

Comment: More information: With the bridged rails, the setup **does** work, if I comment out the lines containing `MP3serial.flush();` and `MP3serial.end();`. However, taking the  bridge away again and plugging the MOSFET back in, same issue: works in the first iteration then fails, but sometimes it starts the audio and then stops.

Comment: With the bridged rails and no MOSFET, what happens when you depower and repower the DFPLAYER via a high-side wire link during the 8 second sleep? Does it then work during the subsequent iteration?

Comment: I removed the MOSFET and added a bride, s.th. both the 5V and GND rails are connected via bridges. This works if I comment out the `flush` and `end` commands. Then, if I pull **either** the 5V or the GND bridge and plug it back in place, it works (It actually works regardless of whether I plug it back in time or not, which seriously confuses me). That being said, if I plug out the 5V bridge, the Arduino draws more than 3 mA in deep sleep (due to serial left on!?), but w/o the GND bridge it draws only ~0.1 mA. The latter is what I'm aiming for, as it shall run for a year on a 1900mAh battery.